# PHP - fread() function

Tags: php

I have simple file ...i got the code from w3schools

When i tried to execute the code

fread() function doesn't return anything

first.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$file = fopen("test.php","r");
fread($file,filesize("test.php"));

?>
```

test.php

```
<?php 
echo "Hello world"; 
?>
```

when i open [localhost/first.php](http://localhost/first.php)

the result is blank page

Comment: Why do you include `test.php` in your question? Is it related in anyway to `first.php` and the problem you're having?

Comment: no but just to be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never capture what you read to display it on the page. Do

```
$contents = fread(...);
if($contents===false):
    //there was an error
else:
    echo $contents;
endif;
```